# Reading through a file, writing to another file with while loop

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm trying to make a program that reads through a text file with a lot of text, splits the text using the Scanner useDelimiter function, and prints the text to another file.

The text in the file to read looks something like this (it is much longer though):

"< wpt sometext> < desc sometext < /dsc> < /wpt>< wpt sometext> < desc sometext < /dsc> < /wpt>" These are waypoints in a GPX-file.

I want it to separate at the "< /wpt>" and as long as it reads another "

But when i print it out to another textfile, it only prints the first waypoint...

Here is my code so far. I created a dummy file to filter out the metadata from the original file. The program should read from this dummy file.

```
public void openFile() {
    Chooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\");
    Chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    Chooser.setDialogTitle("Open file");
    Chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.gpx", "gpx"));
    Chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.txt", "txt"));
    Chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.csv", "csv"));
    int returnVal = Chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    try {
        Dummy = new Scanner(Chooser.getSelectedFile());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException E) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + E);
    }
}

public void createFile() {
    Dummy.useDelimiter("<wpt");
    if (Dummy.hasNext()) {
        String Meta = Dummy.next();
    }
    Dummy.useDelimiter("\\s[<wpt]\\s|\\s[</wpt>]\\s");
    try {
        while (Dummy.hasNext()) {
            String Test = Dummy.next();
            DummyFile = new File("Dummy.txt");
            Output = new PrintWriter(DummyFile);
            Output.print(Test);
            Output.println();
            Output.flush();
            //Output.close();          
        }
        Input = new Scanner(DummyFile).useDelimiter("\\s<wpt\\s*");
        String Final = Input.next();
        boolean Done = false;
        while (Done != true) {
            TestFile = new File("C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
            Writer = new PrintWriter(TestFile);
            Writer.println(Final);
            Writer.flush();
            if (Input.hasNext()) {
                Done = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException EXE) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + EXE);
    }
    Dummy.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You specify it as delimiter :

```
 Dummy.useDelimiter("\\s[<wpt]\\s|\\s[</wpt>]\\s");
```

So, the Scanner looks for token delimited by `" <wpt </wpt> "`.
It is not what you want.
You have some  `<wpt`  "tags" and you want to retrieve content of each one `<wpt>` tag.

You could use a GPX parser or do the parsing manually by reading the file with a `BufferedReader`.

Doing it yourself for handle a single kind of `tag` is really straight.
You read the file content in a buffer and as soon as you detect a `"<wpt" String`, you create a new object and you go on reading the file to value the state of this object, and you do the same thing for the next encountered :`"<wpt" String`, and so on....